# Angular - How to import a module from a JS bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, polyfills, angular-library

I am trying to import a module from a generated Angular library bundle located inside a `vendor` subfolder under `src/`.

**index.html**

```
<head>
...
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./vendor/example/bundles/example.umd.js"></script>
    
</head>
```

Nevertheless, I am having some troubles importing module from this in my `app.module.ts`. Please, any idea of how to do it?

It seems that @angular/core and @angular/common peerDependencies of angular library should also be bundled inside script to work correctly.

I will appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't add a `<script>` tag that refers to a local file because this local file won't be included in the build.

Instead, use the [scripts configuration section](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config) of the `angular.json` file, like this:

```
"scripts": [
    { "input": "src/vendor/example/bundles/example.umd.js" }
]
```

This will embed the `example.umd.js` file inside a dedicated file of the Angular's build. As it's packaged as UMD, an object will be attached to `window` which contains the API of the library you are importing.

In order to stop TypeScript for complaining about a non-existent variable, just add this: `declare var example;` (replace `example` with the real name of the global object).

Comment: The error is reproduced here: `(global = global || self, factory(global.example= {}, global.ng.core, global.rxjs, global.ng2Stompjs, global.ng.common));`  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'core' of undefined**

Comment: It seems that **ng**, **rxjs** and **ng2Stompjs** object properties of global are `undefined`

Comment: I could import the JS file as you suggested, thanks for the info :). Nevertheless I have  some problems when I execute my Angular Application. Please see previous comments, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: That means there are some dependencies to import in order to make your library work. Are you sure that `example` is not an Angular library that should be imported in one of your Angular modules?

Comment: Thanks @Guerric P, only one more question, how can I import module using typescript? I was trying this `import { ExampleModule, ExampleService } from "../vendor/example/bundles/example.umd.js";` nevertheless, it fails in AoT compilation (executing: `npm run build -- --prod --build-optimizer`)

Comment: Please check error: **ERROR in Unexpected value 'ExampleModule in 'example.umd.js' imported by the module 'AppModule in 'app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.**

Comment: Well you should not try to import this library as UMD but as ESM with TypeScript definition files. Ideally, if this library is on NPM, install it with `npm i example`

Comment: Could you give some example of how to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: As remark, i pretend that this library shall not be included on NPM

Comment: Is it an Angular module? Is it available as ESM package (not UMD)?

Comment: Yes, it is an angular module, according to your second question, yes I was using the UMD scripts located in bundles folder, do you mean that i should use the scripts located under fesm folders¿

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222614/discussion-between-alberto-bricio-and-guerric-p).